# Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP to determine colour of row

Tags: php, html, timestamp

I currently have this code:

```
        $rawsql2 = "SELECT 
    *
    FROM 
        _erc_foffices n 
    INNER JOIN 
        _erc_openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        _erc_openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
    WHERE 
    (
        n.id = %d
    );";

    $sql2 = sprintf($rawsql2, mysql_real_escape_string($id));

    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

    /*These if & while statements decide whether or not the information should be displayed. If no results are returned from the query above then an alternative message is shown.*/
    if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    $count=0;
    $day = 1;
    echo "<div class='timetable'><p>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            if ($day=='1') { echo "<b>Sun - </b>";} else if ($day=='3') { echo "<b>Mon - </b>"; } else if ($day=='5') { echo "<b>Tue - </b>"; } else if ($day=='7') { echo "<b>Wed - </b>"; } else if ($day=='9') { echo "<b>Thu - </b>"; } else if ($day=='11') { echo "<b>Fri - </b>"; } else if ($day=='13') { echo "<b>Sat - </b>"; } else { echo "";}
            if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {
     if ($day % 2 == 1) {
         echo "closed";
     }

}
            else{
            echo "" . substr($row["open"], 0, -3) . "-" . substr($row["close"], 0, -3) . " &nbsp;&nbsp; ";
            if ($count % 2 !=0 ){ echo  "<br/>"; } }
$count++;
$day++;

        }
    } else {
            echo "Error";
    }
```

which pulls a timetable from the database, and then display it in the format:

Sun - 08:00-12:30    13:30-16:30
Mon - 09:00-17:00    18:00-20:00  etc

What I want to do now, is if for example, the current say is Sunday, then the Sunday row font would be red. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's possible of course. Check [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions. But if you already have day names, I don't see any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's native date-time format is a unix timestamp, so you can take the value retrieved in your query, and get the day-of-week value with `date('w', $timestamp)`. That returns a value in the range of 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday), and you can use that to determine a color.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm finding it hard to understand the replies and how to do this. Would you mind editing my code so I can learn from how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) mysql function in your query:
`SELECT *, DAYOFWEEK(your_column_name) as dw .....`